# Javascript digital signatures

Tags: javascript, encryption, cryptoapi

To create a digital signature with the client certificate in javascript, there was a function: crypto.signtext() that doesn't work anymore

What is the easiest way to do this now?

Answer (score 1):

[It hasn't gone away](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript_crypto#Signing_text), it's just you have to spell it with a capital `T`. And still being Netscape/Mozilla/Firefox-only, it's of limited usefulness.

Answer (score 0):

For me, the best solution is to use a browser extension like [WebPKI](https://webpki.lacunasoftware.com)